# Is only one SVD computation enough to perform PCA on a matrix and its transpose?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd, transpose, principal-component-analysis

SVD is used in PCA in order to get the mapping to lower dimensions. Is it enough to perform only one SVD in order to get the PCA for the original matrix AND its transpose, considering that the SVD of a matrix gives also the SVD of the transpose of that same matrix?

SVD decomposition of $Y$ and $Y^t$:

$$Y=U\Sigma V^t$$
$$Y^t=V\Sigma^tU^t$$

Solution of PCA for matrix Y:
$$\vec{x}=W^t\vec{y}=U_k^t\vec{y}$$

Comment: Note that PCA assumes that the matrix whose SVD we compute was normalized to have mean $0$. While we do get the SVD of the transpose for free, it is not necessarily true that the transpose has this required mean-zero property

Comment: Oh right, so usually we normalize a dataset in order to perform SVD on it. Then, in order to perform PCA on a transposed dataset, we would first have to normalize the transposed version, and thus we would need to perform SVD again, correct?

Comment: That's right. That said, it should be possible to use the previous computation to find the normalized transposed SVD using the fact that we're finding the SVD to a [rank-1 update](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08369) of a matrix with known SVD.

Comment: Thank you for the help, if you would post this as an answer, I will accept it.